# Setting page title from content file in CodeIgniter (MVC)

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

My CodeIgniter website's controller is set up like this:

```
$this->load->view('head', $data); // Contains <head> stuff
$this->load->view('header', $data); // Nav and sidebars
$this->load->view($this->uri->segment(1), $data); // Main page content
$this->load->view('footer', $data); // Footer
```

My question is about where to store `<title>` tag's content. Ideally it would be with the page content (the 3rd loaded view) but then how do you get that into the `<title>` tag which has been loaded in the first view?

I've read that it's bad to have JavaScript set the title as it won't be compatible with search engine bots.

I've also read a suggestion which said to have a large view file with all the pag

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but can't you just send the `data['title']` to your head view?

Comment: Yes I can. But where does the controller get the value for that from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thought of a way to solve my issue, and I got the idea from http://joshhighland.com/blog/2008/11/09/how-i-do-layouts-and-views-in-codeigniter/. If you look on that page you can see a line like this near the bottom of the first code extract:

```
$layout_data['content_body'] = $this->load->view('home/homePage', $body_data, true);
```

This loads the view as a string into that variable. I will then run a function on that string to extract what I want the title to be (I will store it in an HTML comment) and put it into `$layout_data['pageTitle']`. Then, by following the rest of the layout method on the link, I will be able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

For changing page title this is better way.
In your config file add this parameter:

```
$config['pageTitle'] = 'Book Store';
```

In template page :

```
<title><?=$this->config->config["pageTitle"]?></title>
```

In any page you like change this config in action:

```
$this->config->config["pageTitle"] = $detail[0]['Title'];
```

Every time you can change the title easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite following why you want the  tag in the third view you load rather than in the head (the first view that you load) of your compiled HTML document. Why not have something like:

```
$data['title'] = 'my page title';

$this->load->view('head', $data);
```

Comment: But where would the value for $data['title'] come from or be stored? If I have most of my pages load through the controller's Index function and go to www.mysite.com/somepage how would the controller know somepage's title? This is the issue, I don't know where to store the data.

Comment: I guess I'm not following the real issue, do you have some kind of dynamic setup where your controller doesn't know what content it's loading?  In your example your using "$this->uri->segment(1)" which is the main "view" and which the title should be linked with.  Why not store an associative config array like:

$config['titles'] = array('customer' => 'customer page');

Then in your controller just do $data['title'] = $this->config->item($this->uri->segment(1));

Pass that to your first view (the "head" section) and let codeigniter view loader do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Logicaly your `<title>` tag should be within `<head>` tags and it would make sense to have it in your 'head' view. So your $data array you're passing to head view should contain an element for  tag. From your script I understand you're passing the same $data array for all 4 views? Not very good practise as you may end up passing elements used in one view, but not in the other four. I would recommend forming a different array for each view.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however this doesn't solve my issue. See my response to Greg for more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a helper function?

**Helper** `helpers/header_helper.php`

```
function set_title($title) {
    $ci &= get_instance();
    $ci->header_title = $title;
}

function get_title() {
    $ci &= get_instance();
    return $ci->header_title;
}
```

You may want to set this to **auto-load** in `config/autoload.php`

In your *views* you can then call upon the function `get_title()` and in your *controllers* you can call upon `set_title()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still too new to PHP to understand your answer. So where would I actually store the titles?

Comment: They'd be stored in CodeIgniter's object.

Comment: Sorry @StevenLu you defined function has small error i will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in my style. May it not be perfect, but it solves my maximumpurpose.

I create a helper function named getMyPageTitle().

And there I wrote down the logic of a page title.

The basic part of the logic is I assumed a default title in the config file.

```
            <?php
            function getMyPageTitle(){

                $title = '';
                $ci = &get_instance();

                $default_title = 'My Site';// you can load it from a config file,and that is better option
                // get the view name
                $view = $this->uri->segment(2);
                // check if controller set a page tile
                /* If you want to set a page title for a particular page then always 
                 * named that variable 'pageTitle' as $data['pageTitle'] = 'My page title | For this page'
                 */

                global $pageTitle;

                if($pageTitle){// the controller sets the page title
                    $title = $pageTitle;
                }elseif($view !== ''){//you can include your view name in the page title,,and the view name is not blanks
                    $title = $default_title.' | '. $view;
                }/**
                  * You can write several else if , before or after this or
                  * can change the total logic as you want
                  */
                 else{
                    $title = $default_title;
                }

                return $title;
            }
            ?>
```

And in the view use this

```
<title><?= getMyPageTitle()?></title>
```

I think this solves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

-> Set TITLE tag in template

```
    <title>
        <?php if (!empty($page_title)) echo $page_title;?>
    </title>
```

-> Set $data['page_title'] = ' title name '

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['page_title'] = 'List'; 
        $this->load->view('head', $data); // Contains <head> stuff
        $this->load->view('header', $data); // Nav and sidebars
        $this->load->view($this->uri->segment(1), $data); // Main page content
        $this->load->view('footer', $data); // Footer
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Codeignitor Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Website &mdash; Welcome To Website';
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('index');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function about()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Coachify &mdash; About Us';
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('about');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

In `view/header.php`

```
<title><?= $title; ?></title>
```